# How to understand the JavaScript I am using to call Powershell code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand this JavaScript code. I don't know anything about JavaScript. As I understand this script is calling PowerShell script. But I am unable to understand what is that `indexof` code doing.

I am using this JavaScript on VMWare VRealize orchestrator.

```
var output;
var session;

try {

    session = host.openSession();
    var script =  '& "' + Powershellscript + '" ' + scriptparameter;
    output = session.invokeScript(script);
    var psOutput = output.getHostOutput();
    System.log(psOutput);

    if(psOutput.indexOf("Error In Operation") == -1)
    {
        isPsExecuted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isPsExecuted = false;
    }

} 
finally 
{
    if (session)
    {
        host.closeSession(session.getSessionId());
    }
}
```

Comment: [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psOutput.indexOf("Error In Operation") == -1` means `psOutput` doesn't contain the text "Error In Operation" (case sensitive)

Generally, indexOf returns the place a text/element is found in a string/array.
It returns -1 if it was not found.
More info at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: You've referenced Array.indexOf not String.indexOf as you probably intended.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` checks if the text `'Error In Operation'` is present anywhere in the output of the script. It uses this to detect whether an error happened. 
`indexOf` returns the index of a given string in another string

psOutput.indexOf("Error In Operation") == -1 means that Error In Operation was not present anywhere in psOutput  (-1 is returned when the string is not found)

Comment: i get this error -  null
 TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of null

Comment: That would happen if psOutput is null.